# How do one show that the quotient space is a projective manifold?

Tags: complex-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, kahler-manifolds

I want to prove the following statement.

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain, and $\Gamma \subset \text{Aut}(\Omega)$ be the subgroup acting totally discontinuously on $\Omega$ without fixed points such that the quotient space $X = \Omega \setminus \Gamma$ is a compact complex manifold. Then $X$ is a projective manifold.

My idea is to use the Kodaira Emdedding theorem by constructing a positive holomorphic line bundle. However, I am not sure how to do so. Can you provide me with some ideas how to do so? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Projectivity of such quotients was actually proven by Kodaira himself in Theorem 6 in

*Kodaira, Kunihiko*, [**On Kähler varieties of restricted type. (An intrinsic characterization of algebraic varieties.)**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1969701), Ann. Math. (2) 60, 28-48 (1954). [ZBL0057.14102](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0057.14102).

In brief, the canonical bundle of the quotient manifold is positive (one uses a curvature computation for the Bergman metric on $K_\Omega$), hence, Kodaira's embedding theorem applies.